# How to allow users to visit web pages

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes, laravel-8

I'm trying to allow only those users whose data is in the database to access the pages by using auth middleware in laravel8.
i did this in the routes/web.php, but it is not allowing any user to visit the page whether his data is in database or not, it's redirecting them to the login page.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'],function () {
    Route::get('profile', [UserController::class,'profile']);    
});
```

i only changed the routes, do i have to make changes to other files too?

Comment: auth middleware needs user login to system, there is no authenticated user in your system,so it redirects to login page

Comment: i don't know how to achieve that, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install an [`authentication`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication) provider of some sort. Laravel provides a few [`starter kits`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#install-a-starter-kit) to get up and running with authentication in Laravel a little easier.

You possibly want to look at one of the kits such as [`JetStream`](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/installation.html) or [`Breeze`](https://github.com/laravel/breeze) which provide a lot of the boilerplate for you.

**Update**

If you don't want a full featured kit with all the views and such, you can use [`Fortify`](https://github.com/laravel/fortify) which gives you just the code for implementing authentication. You're responsible for implementing views and workflow.

Comment: Thank you, but i'm trying to achieve that without using any kits.
i already have login and sign up pages and that's working perfectly fine

Comment: @VikasGiri I have updated my answer for you.